# ImageMagick - rounding the alpha channel

Tags: imagemagick, alpha, monochrome

I have an image which is white on a transparent background, but the white has some alpha channel around the object's edges (due to anti-aliasing). How could I make this pure white-on-transparent, by rounding the alpha channel so > 0.5 becomes white and <= 0.5 becomes transparent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to threshold the alpha (transparency) channel at 50% thereby forcing all transparencies under 50% to zero and transparencies over 50% to 100%. Like this:

```
convert image.png -channel alpha -threshold 50% out.png
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this worked fine, and actually more useful than just rounding as I can tweak the %ge figure.

Comment: Excellent - I love it when a plan comes together. By the way, if you need to tweak, and want finer granularity, you can remove the percent sign and use a value between 0-65535, so `-threshold 32768` would be equivalent to 50%. I am assuming you have a 16-bit quantisation ImageMagick - i.e. Q16.